# Aplicar @click a un elemento dinamico

Tags: nuxt, vue2

Tengo un código que tiene dos botones, y cada uno de ellos muestra un contenido distinto.
Yo quiero que antes de cambiar de tab se verifiquen ciertas cosas, por lo que pongo `@click="preventTab($event)"` en el  (img 1).

Todo funciona perfecto, excepto lo siguiente: la funcion `preventTab` se ejecuta si hago click en el elemento `<span>`, pero en realidad yo necesito que se aplique a su elemento padre, (un `<a>`) cosa que se genera automaticamente con bootstrap (img 2)

Quisiera encontrar la manera que la funcion "preventTab" se aplique al hacer click en el `a.nav-link` en lugar del `span` con `class="change-tab"`.

```
<tabs tabContentClasses="card shadow mt-2">
  <tab-pane v-for="(item, index) in idiomas" :key="index">
    <span slot="title" class="change-tab" ref="changeTab"  @click="preventTab($event)"> {{ item.nombre }} </span>

    <collapse :multiple-active="false">
      <collapse-item ref="menu" name="1">
        <h5 slot="title" class="mb-0" @click="($event) => {toggleCollapse(1, $event)}">
          Edit menu principal
        </h5>
        <Menu :pos="1" :lang="item.codigo" />
      </collapse-item>
      <collapse-item ref="menu" name="2">
        <h5 slot="title" class="mb-0" @click="toggleCollapse(2, $event)">
          Edit menu secundario
        </h5>
        <Menu :pos="2" :lang="item.codigo" />
      </collapse-item>
    </collapse>
  </tab-pane>
</tabs>

preventTab($event){
  let change = this.$store.getters["watchers/watchMenu"];
  if (change) {
    $event.stopPropagation()
     swal
      .fire({
         title: "Remember that you must save each menu clicking on Save Changes.",
        showDenyButton: false,
        showCancelButton: false,
        confirmButtonText: "Ok",
      })
  }
}
```

> IMG 1

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> IMG 2

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]